# AES_ENCRYPT AES_DECRYPT how to get key if know encrypted list and one decrypted value

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

Suppose there is table with list of logins values which are encrypted. Suppose I know 100% what login "abcd" was encrypted and is in the list.

Is it possible to get key value in such case? Can someone suggest how to get a key value?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext

Comment: This is multi-target attack, If you would have different keys then with a multi-target attack you can find some keys faster. The expected cost of finding a key from t target is 2^{128}/t. In single-case AES in koen to be [KPA secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63884/18298)